# Network Folder Security

Tags: windows, vb.net, security, networking, directory

I have a treeview control which is being used to browse various folder on the users system drive.  It can also be set up to connect network folders using UNC paths e.g "\server\files".  At the moment I'm getting a list of Directories by using My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories however this obviously fails when the folder is password protected.

Is there a way that I can get Windows to open the credentials dialog as you would see in Windows Explorer and deal with the credentials side so then the user name & password is cached as well?

I'm not allowed to physically map drives by the way.

Thanks for any help.

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use P/Invoke to call a Windows API function, specifically WNetAddConnection3.

See the answer to my question here: [Can I force windows to challenge a user for authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379941/can-i-force-windows-to-challenge-a-user-for-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using Hex values
Private Const CONNECT_INTERACTIVE As Integer = &H8
Private Const CONNECT_PROMPT As Integer = &H10